# RecyclervIew not showing SQlite Database data properly

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using `Sqlite` database along with `Recyclerview` and `Cardview` to show the data in `Recyclerview` .My `Recyclerview` is showing the data but ,it is not showing it in a sequence, it is behaving abnormally, i have added 6 items,but is showing 18 items with the repeated names and with a lot of spaces after every item.What is the issue.Here is my code..

**databasehelper.java**

```
public class databasehandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Foodmanager";

    // Food table name
    private static final String TABLE_FOOD = "Food";
    private static databasehandler dbhelper;

    // Food Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID= "id";
    private static final String FOOD_CATEGORY = "Food_category";
    private static final String FOOD_ITEM = "Food_item";
    private static final String  PROTEINS = "Proteins";
    private static final String  FAT = "Fat";
    private static final String  CARB = "carb";
    private static final String  CALORIES = "calories";

    public static synchronized databasehandler getInstance(Context context) {
        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.

        if (dbhelper == null) {
           dbhelper = new databasehandler(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return dbhelper;
    }


    public databasehandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_FOOD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOOD +" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Food_category TEXT,Food_item TEXT,Proteins REAL,Fat REAL,carb REAL,calories REAL)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_FOOD_TABLE);

    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FOOD);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**,
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    public void addfood(food_items food_item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FOOD_CATEGORY, food_item.getfood_category());
        values.put(FOOD_ITEM, food_item.getfood_item());
        values.put(PROTEINS, food_item.getproteins());
        values.put(FAT, food_item.getfat());
        values.put(CARB, food_item.getcarb());
        values.put(CALORIES, food_item.getcalorie());

        db.insert(TABLE_FOOD, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single food item
   public food_items getfood_item(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_FOOD, new String[] { FOOD_CATEGORY,
                        FOOD_ITEM, PROTEINS,FAT,CARB,CALORIES }, FOOD_CATEGORY + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

       assert cursor != null;
       food_items food_item = new food_items(cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(1), Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(2)),Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(3)),
                Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(4)),Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(5)));
        // return contact
        return food_item;
    }
    public String getfood_category(){
        String food_category="";
        String selectQuery="SELECT  FOOD_CATEGORY FROM " + TABLE_FOOD;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                food_category=cursor.getString(0);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return food_category;
    }


      public List<food_items> getAllfood_items() {
        List<food_items> food_item_list = new ArrayList<>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FOOD;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
               food_items food_item = new food_items();
//                food_item.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                food_item.setfood_category(cursor.getString(0));
                food_item.setfood_item(cursor.getString(1));
                food_item.setproteins(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(2)));
                food_item.setfat(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(3)));
                food_item.setcarb(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(4)));
                food_item.setcalorie(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(5)));

                food_item_list.add(food_item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return food_item_list;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updatefood(food_items food_item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FOOD_CATEGORY, food_item.getfood_category());
        values.put(FOOD_ITEM, food_item.getfood_item());
        values.put(PROTEINS, food_item.getproteins());
        values.put(FAT, food_item.getfat());
        values.put(CARB, food_item.getcarb());
        values.put(CALORIES, food_item.getcalorie());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_FOOD, values, FOOD_CATEGORY + " = ?",
                new String[] { food_item.getfood_category() });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deletefood(food_items food_item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_FOOD, FOOD_CATEGORY + " = ?",
                new String[] { food_item.getfood_category() });
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getfoodCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_FOOD;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

**foodactivity.java**

```
  public class food_activity extends com.samarth.lightweight.base_Activity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private food_category_adapter adapter;
    databasehandler db;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.food_category, frameLayout);

        db=databasehandler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        preparedata();

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);

        setTitle("Calories in food");

        adapter=new food_category_adapter(this,db.getAllfood_items());


        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
//        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    }

    public void preparedata() {

            db.addfood(new food_items("Dairy and Egg Products","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f));
            db.addfood(new food_items("Spices and Herbs","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f));
            db.addfood(new food_items("Fats and Oils","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f));
            db.addfood(new food_items("Soups, Sauces, and Gravies","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f));
            db.addfood(new food_items("Fruits","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f));
            db.addfood(new food_items("Vegetables","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f));

    }

}
```

**food_Category_adapter**

```
     public class food_category_adapter extends
            RecyclerView.Adapter<com.samarth.lightweight.database.food_category_adapter.ViewHolder>
    {
        private static final int TYPE_HEAD=0;
        private static final int TYPE_LIST=1;
        public String category;


        private Context mContext;
        private List<food_items> food_items;

        public food_category_adapter(Context context,List<food_items> food_itemses) {
            mContext=context;
            food_items=food_itemses;
        }


        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


           if(viewType==TYPE_LIST) {
               View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                       .inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);

               return new ViewHolder(itemView,viewType);
           }
            else if(viewType==TYPE_HEAD)
           {
               View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                       .inflate(R.layout.header_recycle_view, parent, false);

               return new ViewHolder(itemView,viewType);
           }
            return null;
        }


        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            int view_type;
            public TextView food_category;
            public ImageView food_image;
            public ImageView header_image;


            public ViewHolder(View view,int viewType) {
                super(view);

                if(viewType==TYPE_LIST) {
                    food_category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.food_category);
                    food_image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    view_type=1;

                    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            category=food_category.getText().toString();
                            Intent intent = new Inten

t(v.getContext(),food_item_description.class);
                        intent.putExtra("category_food",category);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }) ;

            }
            else if(viewType==TYPE_HEAD)
            {
                header_image=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.food_main);
                view_type=0;
            }
        }
    }





    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(com.samarth.lightweight.database.food_category_adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
    {
        if(viewHolder.view_type==TYPE_LIST){
            com.samarth.lightweight.database.food_items food_item=food_items.get(position-1);
            viewHolder.food_category.setText(food_item.getfood_category());
        }
        else if(viewHolder.view_type==TYPE_HEAD)
        {
            viewHolder.header_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.food_category1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if(food_items!=null)
        return food_items.size()+1;
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if(position==0)
            return TYPE_HEAD;
        return TYPE_LIST;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because every time your start your app `preparedata` will be executed and same data will be inserted into data base and later will be displayed by `Recyclerview`.

if you want to insert your data only once then you should do this inside `onCreate` of your `databasehandler`

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_FOOD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOOD +" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,Food_category TEXT,Food_item TEXT,Proteins REAL,Fat REAL,carb REAL,calories REAL)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_FOOD_TABLE);
        // execute your insert commands here to insert data only once  
        addfood(new food_items("Dairy and Egg Products","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f),db);
        addfood(new food_items("Spices and Herbs","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f),db);
        addfood(new food_items("Fats and Oils","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f),db);
        addfood(new food_items("Soups, Sauces, and Gravies","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f),db);
        addfood(new food_items("Fruits","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f),db);
        addfood(new food_items("Vegetables","Milk",0f,0f,0f,0f),db);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

and in use `addfood` as overloaded method mean now there will be two `addfood` functions and this one will receive `db` as second parameter

```
 public void addfood(food_items food_item, SQLiteDatabase db ) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(FOOD_CATEGORY, food_item.getfood_category());
        values.put(FOOD_ITEM, food_item.getfood_item());
        values.put(PROTEINS, food_item.getproteins());
        values.put(FAT, food_item.getfat());
        values.put(CARB, food_item.getcarb());
        values.put(CALORIES, food_item.getcalorie());

        db.insert(TABLE_FOOD, null, values);
    }
```

Note : after modification , you have to uninstall your app to delete old `sqlite` data and then run the modified code

Comment: Sir if i want to add more items in my database ,will i have to make a new ContentValues object everytime or is there some other solution for this ?

Comment: @samarthkejriwal try updated answer , you can create `values` as global variable and initialize it inside `oncreate` mean declare `ContentValues values` at class level like `CALORIES` and do `values = new ContentValues();` inside `oncreate` , but `static` mean data of `values` will not go away so old values will be there if later you want to use `values` object

Comment: I got your email-id.can i mail your for any query related to java and android ??

Comment: @samarthkejriwal i am glad i could help and happy coding :)

Comment: @samarthkejriwal i like to help though i got a job too so better option is , you can post your question here ( SO is full of great members , you will get help ) and tag me in comments section , i will be notified and try to help ASAP :)

Comment: Ok sir i will tag you in my question and please have a look at it .Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @samarthkejriwal just don't worry , SO guys are awesome , you will surely get help , just make sure your question have all the details and error logs with code and provide details when asked and surely most of time you will get response in 1 - 7 minutes

Comment: Thankyou sir .It was a nice short meeting .Definitely learned something new..In case i am unable to get a good answer from SO ,then i think you will always be there.